# SUMPRODUCT has mismatched range error in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a Google Spreadsheet where I have maintained the results of some students. I need to display the number of students **passed** or **failed** per **class** from the **filtered rows** only. I am trying to obtain the same by using the following function:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUBTOTAL(3,OFFSET($B$2:$B$9,ROW($B$2:$B$9)-MIN(ROW($B$2:$B$9)),,1)),($C$2:$C$9=G$4)*($D$2:$D$9="PASS"))
```

The above function works fine if the spreadsheet is downloaded and opened in Excel. But in Google Spreadsheet, it returns the following error:

```
SUMPRODUCT has mismatched range sizes. Expected row count: 1, column count: 1. Actual row count: 8, column count: 1.
```

[image]

Can anyone help me with a fix?

[Link to the Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1noU-USIFm8QM4kcnGrbWwXCpX0ZUeEyh/edit?usp=sharing&ouid=109907677788022327633&rtpof=true&sd=true)

Answer (score 2):

Use the following formula in `F4`:

```
=QUERY(
{C2:D,ARRAYFORMULA(COUNTIFS(C2:C,C2:C,D2:D,D2:D))}, 
"select Col2, max(Col3) where Col3 > 0 group by Col2 pivot Col1 order by Col2 desc")
```

The resulting table will dynamically expand as you add more classes and test results to the data table.

[Link to Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yf68CUb0ChYNB5eYls2zzBcy0MxMs_Yv/edit#gid=1065659396)